# git noob: how to copy just the updated files to a target directory?

Tags: asp.net, git

I'm using Git for an ASP.net site.

I push changes to the repo.

Then I go to the server, fetch from repo and merge local.

--> Now, I just want to copy the files that have changed over to my Inetpub folder.

Is there an easy way to do this with a Git Bash command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git show --pretty="format:" --name-only HEAD
```

Gives you the files that were changed in the latest commit in a one-file-per-line list. HEAD can be replaced by any git treeish, such as a commit sha1 or HEAD^ for the parent of the latest commit, etc.

You directly use this to copy files by piping it to `xargs` and `copy` using either the -J or -I switch for OS X and linux respectively:

```
git show --pretty="format:" --name-only bd5b6d356374e2cd64250f68c94e3a1738592a9f | xargs -I % cp % destination_folder
```